# Adjusting a solution.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

Here is the questions:

Let $U_{i}$ be a path-component of $X = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus J.$

$(a)$ Let $U_{j}$ be any other component of $X.$ Show that $U_{j} \subseteq X\setminus \overline{U_{i}}.$

$(b)$ Show that the boundary $\partial U_{i}$ of $U_{i}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2 $ can not contain any point of any $U_{j},$ whether $j=i$ or $j \neq i.$

**Here are my solutions to them:**

$(a)$

Since by the given we have that $X = \bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}}$ where the subsets $U_{i}$ are the path components of $X$ and since these subsets are pairwise disjoint. Then we have that $U_{j} \subseteq X\setminus \overline{U_{i}}$ as required.\

$(b)$

First. If $j=i.$

By the given definition of the boundary $$\partial U = \overline{U} \cap \{X \setminus U\}.$$ We know that the boundary $\partial U_{i}$ of $U_{i}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2 $ can not contain any point of any $U_{i}.$

Second. If $j \neq i.$

This is also clear from the given definition of the boundary and because $X = \bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}}$ where the subsets $U_{i}$ are the path components of $X$ and these subsets are pairwise disjoint.

**Here is a comment about the drawback in the given solution:**

"Why does $U_{i}$ contained the complement of the remaining U_j imply that it is contained in the CLOSURE of that union?"

Could anyone help me adjust this part of my solution please?